# Issue with unity JsonUtility.FromJson

Tags: c#, json

I'm having an issue while trying to read a json in unity. I get this message "ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Invalid value.". My JSON looks like:

```
[{"equipo":"Boca","pj":"5","pg":"3","pp":"2"}] and it is ok in unity.
```

Here is my info class

```
[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    public string equipo;
    public int pj;
    public int pg;
    public int pp;
}
```

And here is the coroutine that I call in the awake function

```
IEnumerator RequestCorutine()
{
    var req = new WWW("http://localhost/test/item.php?team=Boca");
    yield return req;
    print(req.text);

    //var json = req.text;
    string json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req.bytes, 3, 
    req.bytes.Length - 3);
    Response response = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(json);
    print("Equipo: " + response.equipo + " PJ: " + response.pj + " PG: " + 
    response.pg + " PP: " + response.pp);
}
```

I get the error in this line: `Response response = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(json);`

I apologize for my English, is not that good. Thanks.

Comment: Are the `[` and `]` part of the json?

Comment: That's not supposed to be there?

Comment: See my answer. Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[{"equipo":"Boca","pj":"5","pg":"3","pp":"2"}]`

should be

`{"equipo":"Boca","pj":5,"pg":3,"pp":2}`

because square brackets are used to declare arrays in json. You were declaring a `List<Response>` instead of a single `Response`. Also, I removed the quotes around the numbers.

Comment: I understand, how can I could I remove them from there?

Comment: try removing the quotes around the numbers like this : `{"equipo":"Boca","pj":5,"pg":3,"pp":2}`

Comment: Sorry for the three coments xD It worked, I've changed the line where i declare the json for the commented above, and it worked, thanks you very much. Just tell me how can I commend you, I'm a new one here :D

Comment: Awesome! Welcome to StackOverflow! You just need to click the checkmark at the left of my answer to accept it :D